# Running an m file compiled in dll in matlab

Tags: matlab, dll, matlab-deployment

So I have an m file that I compiled in C dll form using the Matlab compiler.Note the compiled dll file was originally a matlab file named 'matFunction.m' .Now I want to run this dll from my matlab code. _I am doing the following

```
loadlibrary compiledDLL.dll compiledDLL.h
calllib('compiledDLL','matfunction')
```

but I am getting the error that

```
Error using calllib
Method not found
```

I have also used

```
 loadlibrary compiledDLL.dll compiledDLL.h
 calllib('compiledDLL','matfunction.m')
```

but I am getting the same error. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong, and how I run this dll in my matlab  code.

Comment: loadlibrary is a function, is it not? ie `loadlibrary(dll,hfile)`? I could be wrong

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/loadlibrary.html

Answer (score 0):

`loadlibrary` is a function. The proper syntax is

```
loadlibrary(dll,hfile)
```

as per the [documentation.](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/loadlibrary.html)

The documentation also explicitly states *not* to call the function if the library is already loaded in memory. You can use

```
tf = libisloaded(libname)
```

to test whether the library is already loaded in memory or not.

Furthermore, when using `calllib`, make sure you pass in the proper arguments for your function as well:

```
[x1,...,xN] = calllib(libname,funcname,arg1,...,argN)
```